# so many problem to my homepage error

Tags: error, xml

this is for a day event
what problem? 
my homepage server CPU is many sometimes 100%
to very slowly or not opened my homepage

this is my systeml.log copy

```
2016-02-04T05:18:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:18:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:24:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:24:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:24:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:25:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:25:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:25:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:30:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:30:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:30:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:49:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:49:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T05:49:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T06:33:46+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T06:33:46+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T06:33:46+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/black.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/black.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/main-banner1.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/main-banner1.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/Untitled-16.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/Untitled-16.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/asd.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/asd.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/123456.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/123456.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/Untitled-15.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://letmicrowave.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/banners/Untitled-15.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
2016-02-04T07:08:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/magento/skin/adminhtml/default/MAG090198_Layout2/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/core.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/directory.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog_msrp.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/payment.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout1/layout/sales.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/billing_agreement.xml
2016-02-04T07:25:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/recurring_profile.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

First, did you install any new extension before this started?

Second: lets read your error log.

```
2016-02-04T05:18:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

This means the layout xml cannot be parsed.

Looks like you have an XML file in the layout folders which seems to have been html encoded? Possible been edited (and saved) in an editor that thought this was html, and converted all the xml to html entities, or a bad bad module.

```
< has become &lt; etc (html entities)
```

Search the entire layout folder of the store code (starting at '.../design/frontend') for the occurrence of the string `"&lt;"` 
That will give the file in question that is causing the issues

The rest seems to be missing images.

Solve the xml layout issue first. Could just be the cuase of all other issues.